# How I can use a single stored procedure for data insertion in multiple tables in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Suppose I have many tables in my database. Every time I will insert data in any table. So, can I use a single stored procedure for all my data insertion in every table, instead of writing one stored procedure for each table?

In this scenario, each time I will pass table name and parameters dynamically to the stored procedure. If yes, can anyone give some basic idea how to perform this? If any extra information is required, please ask.

Thanks and regards,
Rizwan Gazi.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea.  Why would you want to treat every table the same?  There is business logic that needs to accompany each table separately.  That would be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I just thought that if I have 100 tables, then I will have to write 100 stored procedures. So i was thinking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with dynamic SQL and build the insert statement on the fly. *THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED* but it should solve the problem you're asking about.

(I haven't run this code, but you can see what is being accomplished here with building the insert string and then executing it)

In this procedure, you pass in the table name, columns and values you care about and fire it off in a row based operation.  With some minor tweaks you would be able to make it set based as well.

```
create procedure dbo.TableInsert
@tablename varchar(100)
, @columnlist varchar(max)
, @valueslist varchar(max)
as
begin
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 
'insert into ' + @tablename
+ '(' + @columnlist + ')'
+ ' VALUES (' + @valueslist + ')'

print(@sql)

sp_executesql (@sql)

end
go
```

Execution would look something like this:

```
exec dbo.TableInsert
@tablename = 'TestTable'
, @columnlist = 'col1, col2, col3'
, @valuelist = '1,2,3'
```

Text insert would be a little trickier in this version since you have to wrap it around in single quotes.

```
exec dbo.TableInsert
@tablename = 'TestTable'
, @columnlist = 'col1, col2, col3'
, @valuelist = '''1'',''2'',''3'''
```

Comment: I think this is the solution, I was looking for, you provided. Thanks dear.

Comment: You're welcome honey.  Mark it as the answer if it works for you.

Comment: It worked sir. But I had to use nvarchar instead of varchar at each place. Once again many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something using dynamic SQL to build a query and then run it using:
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)
(Assuming MS SQL Server)

Not sure I'd recommend it though and will probably be a total nightmare to test and maintain.  Having different sprocs would be easier to test and maintain going forward and would perform better as the different sprocs would have separate query plans.

If you are working in code you could use a [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) to deal with basic CRUD stuff.